# Looping through a list and appending to a new one

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp. I'm trying to write a function that will take a list of dotted lists (representing the quantities of coins of a certain value), e.g.

```
((1 . 50) (2 . 20) (3 . 10)) ;; one 50 cent coin, two 20 cent coins, three 10 cent coins
```

and then convert it to list each coin by value, e.g.

```
(50 20 20 10 10 10)
```

Shouldn't be too hard, right? This is what I have so far. It returns NIL at the moment, though. Any ideas on fixing this?

```
(defun fold-out (coins)
  (let ((coins-list (list)))
    (dolist (x coins)
      (let ((quantity (car x)) (amount (cdr x)))
        (loop for y from 0 to quantity
          do (cons amount coins-list))))
   coins-list))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can use `loop`, simply do

```
(defun fold-out (coins)
  (loop 
    for (quantity . amount) in coins
    nconc (make-list quantity :initial-element amount)))
```

alternatively, using `dolist`:

```
(defun fold-out (coins)
  (let ((rcoins (reverse coins)) (res nil))
    (dolist (c rcoins)
      (let ((quantity (car c)) (amount (cdr c)))
        (dotimes (j quantity) (push amount res))))
    res))
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions are really helpful, as I am just now getting acquainted with the language.

Comment: You're welcome, and you were pretty close: replace `cons` with `push`, and `loop ... to` with `loop ... below` or `loop repeat quantity` in your initial code, and the result would have been correct (though reversed).

Comment: Aha, neat. Looking at the docs for `nconc` now, I see it is a function for concatenating lists. But in the solution above, it only gets called with one argument at a time... so where is the concatenation happening? Is it the loop macro that's taking care of it?

Comment: It's great to see somebody go through the code instead of just copy-pasting it for some assignment!  `nconc` here is a keyword of the `loop` macro, not the function itself. So yes the macro is taking care of the proper call to the `nconc` function.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Especially since `nconc` isn't preceded by a bracket. And this actually is not an assignment; I stumbled on Paul Graham's textbook on Lisp some time ago and I've been learning it ever since. It's good fun! A lot funner than some of the Algol-type languages, at least.

Comment: Then you have come to the right place. I consider myself to be a beginner but there are a few very good common lispers here on SO. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

If I were to do this, I'd probably use nested loops:

```
(defun fold-out (coins)
  (loop for (count . value) in coins
     append (loop repeat count
                  collect value)))
```

Saves a fair bit of typing, manual accumulating-into-things and is, on the whole, relatively readable. Could do with more docstring, and maybe some unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(cons amount coins-list)` returns a new list, but it doesn't modify `coins-list`; that's why the end result is NIL.

So you could change it to `(setf coins-list (cons amount coins-list))` which will explicitly modify `coins-list`, and that will work.

However, in the Lisp way of doing things (functional programming), we try not to modify things like that. Instead, we make each expression return a value (a new object) which builds on the input values, and then pass that new object to another function. Often the function that the object gets passed to is the same function that does the passing; that's recursion.